# How to display D3 Chart using directive?

Tags: angularjs, d3.js, angularjs-directive

I'm trying to display a Pie Chart From a JSON object.

When I try with this Object it works:

```
[{
  "id": "id1",
  "name": "the name 1",
  "values": [{
    "age": "One",
    "population": 5
  }, {
    "age": "Two",
    "population": 2
  }, {
    "age": "Three",
    "population": 9
  }, {
    "age": "Four",
    "population": 7
  }, {
    "age": "Five",
    "population": 4
  }, {
    "age": "Six",
    "population": 3
  }, {
    "age": "Seven",
    "population": 9
  }]
}]
```

but with only this:

```
[{
  "age": "One",
  "population": 5
}, {
  "age": "Two",
  "population": 2
}, {
  "age": "Three",
  "population": 9
}, {
  "age": "Four",
  "population": 7
}, {
  "age": "Five",
  "population": 4
}, {
  "age": "Six",
  "population": 3
}, {
  "age": "Seven",
  "population": 9
}]
```

This is my code:

```js
 var app = angular.module("d3Test", ['d3Test.directives']);



 angular.module('d3Test.directives', [])



 .controller('IndicatorsCtrl', function($scope, Indicators) {
       $scope.datas = '[{ "age": "One",  "population": 5 },{ "age": "Two", "population": 2 }]';


       .factory('Indicators', function($resource) {
         return $resource('datas.json');
       })

        angular.module('d3Test.directives', []).
directive('graph', function () {
 return {
  restrict: 'E',
  scope: {
   values: '='
  },
  link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
   scope.$watch('values', function(values) {
    if(values) { 
     console.log('values from directive: ', values); 
     
     var width = 960,
     height = 500,
     radius = Math.min(width, height) / 2;
     
     var color = d3.scale.ordinal()
      .range(["#98abc5", "#8a89a6", "#7b6888", "#6b486b", "#a05d56", "#d0743c", "#ff8c00"]);
     
     var arc = d3.svg.arc()
      .outerRadius(radius - 10)
      .innerRadius(0);
     
     var pie = d3.layout.pie()
      .sort(null)
      .value(function(d) { 
       return d.population; 
      });
     
     var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
      .attr("width", width)
      .attr("height", height)
      .append("g")
      .attr("transform", "translate(" + width / 2 + "," + height / 2 + ")");
     
     
     
      values.forEach(function(d) {
       d.population = +d.population;
      });
      
      var g = svg.selectAll(".arc")
       .data(pie(values))
       .enter().append("g")
       .attr("class", "arc");
      
      g.append("path")
       .attr("d", arc)
       .style("fill", function(d) { return color(d.data.age); });
      
      g.append("text")
       .attr("transform", function(d) { return "translate(" + arc.centroid(d) + ")"; })
       .attr("dy", ".35em")
       .style("text-anchor", "middle")
       .text(function(d) { return d.data.age; });

    }
   })
  }
 }
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <script data-require="angular.js@*" data-semver="1.0.7" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.0.7/angular.js"></script>
  <script data-require="angular-resource@1.0.7" data-semver="1.0.7" src="http://code.angularjs.org/1.0.7/angular-resource.min.js"></script>
  <script data-require="d3@*" data-semver="3.2.2" src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.2.2/d3.v3.min.js"></script>
  <script src="script.js"></script>
</head>

<body ng-app="d3Test">
  <div ng-controller="IndicatorsCtrl">


    <p>datas: {{datas}}</p>
    <p>values: {{datas[0].values}}</p>

  </div>



</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you're probably calling your `<graph />` directive wrong (either that or modify your directive to 2-way bind the `compositeObject` and then call `compositeObject.values`); The way your directive is written currently, you should be passing in the values, not the object.

Also if you want your `<graph />` to automatically update if any of the data changes you'll need to do some sort of deep `$watch` (pass in a value of `true` as the third argument).  I wrapped these d3 charts for a dashboard in Angular myself a while back... [although consider using a library for your charts](http://krispo.github.io/angular-nvd3/#/quickstart).

Here is a working an example from your code (I used 1.0.8 instead of 1.0.7 because your links were https):

https://plnkr.co/edit/KTLMV2ObafZAkLr11Gxy?p=preview

**app.js**

```
var app = angular.module("d3Test", ['ngResource'])
.controller('IndicatorsCtrl', function($scope, Indicators) {
  $scope.datas = [{
    "age": "One",
    "population": 5
  }, {
    "age": "Two",
    "population": 2
  }];
})
.factory('Indicators', function($resource) {
  return $resource('datas.json');
})
.directive('graph', function() {
  return {
    restrict: 'E',
    scope: {
      values: '='
    },
    link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
      scope.$watch('values', function(values) {
        if (values) {
          console.log('values from directive: ', values);

          var width = 960,
            height = 500,
            radius = Math.min(width, height) / 2;

          var color = d3.scale.ordinal()
            .range(["#98abc5", "#8a89a6", "#7b6888", "#6b486b", "#a05d56", "#d0743c", "#ff8c00"]);

          var arc = d3.svg.arc()
            .outerRadius(radius - 10)
            .innerRadius(0);

          var pie = d3.layout.pie()
            .sort(null)
            .value(function(d) {
              return d.population;
            });

          var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
            .attr("width", width)
            .attr("height", height)
            .append("g")
            .attr("transform", "translate(" + width / 2 + "," + height / 2 + ")");



          values.forEach(function(d) {
            d.population = +d.population;
          });

          var g = svg.selectAll(".arc")
            .data(pie(values))
            .enter().append("g")
            .attr("class", "arc");

          g.append("path")
            .attr("d", arc)
            .style("fill", function(d) {
              return color(d.data.age);
            });

          g.append("text")
            .attr("transform", function(d) {
              return "translate(" + arc.centroid(d) + ")";
            })
            .attr("dy", ".35em")
            .style("text-anchor", "middle")
            .text(function(d) {
              return d.data.age;
            });

        }
      })
    }
  }
});
```

**index.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <title>AngularJS Plunker</title>
  <script>
    document.write('<base href="' + document.location + '" />');
  </script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
  <script data-require="angular.js@1.0.x" src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.0.8/angular.js" data-semver="1.0.8"></script>
  <script data-require="angular.js@1.0.x" src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.0.8/angular-resource.js" data-semver="1.0.8"></script>
  <script data-require="d3@*" data-semver="3.2.2" src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.2.2/d3.v3.min.js"></script>
  <script src="app.js"></script>
</head>

<body ng-app="d3Test">
  <div ng-controller="IndicatorsCtrl">
    <graph values="values"></graph>
  </div>

</html>
```

Comment: thank you for your answer it should work like this.. I'm working now with NVD3 angular.